# How to create several files with addUsingPath in a batch?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, pnp-js-core, batch

I'm trying to use pnp/js to create a batched web and add new files to a folder with `addUsingPath` with this code:

```
    const sp: SPFI = spfi().using(SPBrowser({ baseUrl: options.baseUrl }))
    const [batchedSP, execute] = sp.web.batched();
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
        const file: any = files[i];
        batchedSP
            .getFolderByServerRelativePath(file.folder)
            .files
            .addUsingPath(file.filename, file.data)
            .then((f: any) => f.file.getJSON() as Promise<any>)
    }
    await execute();
```

but it fails throwing this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [500] Internal Server Error ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, System.IO.IOException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"I/O error occurred."}}}
```

By replacing `batchedSP`with `sp.web` it works.

Could you give me any advice or explain what I'm missing to properly understand the batching feature? I have to create several files from rows of an excel file and batching could speed up the task. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

pnpjs batching is not as easy as it seems. In version 3.14.0 addUsingPath doesn´t work for me at all (for folders): when execute is called, no HTTP request is sent.

The problematic part is, that a batch is a single request that is sent to SP when calling execute. If the library internally needs an additional SP roundtrib to gather informations, the batch will only contain the internal requests, not the one the developer wants to do.

e.g. I retrieve files with ServerRelativeUrl from a library and then I want to move all of them in a batch:

```
const [batch, executeBatch] = sp.web.batched();
chunk.forEach(({ File: { ServerRelativeUrl } }) =>
{
    const sourcePath = ServerRelativeUrl;
    const targetPath = sourcePath.replace("/SourcePath/", "/TargetPath/");
    void batch.getFileByServerRelativePath(sourcePath)
        .moveByPath(targetPath, false, false)
        .catch(x => { errors.push(x); });
});
await executeBatch();
if (errors.length)
    throw errors;
```

The `catch()` and `errors` construct is my workaround to throw errors occuring inside a batch request.
In 3.14.0 this batch does not work, because `moveByPath()` internally calls `await this.select("ServerRelativeUrl")();`
Thats why my batch only includes requests as:

```
GET https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativePath(decodedUrl='%2Fsites%2F***%2FSourcePath%2Ffolder1%2Ffile.pdf')?%24select=ServerRelativeUrl HTTP/1.1
```

https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/6fb44877a1a3788b6202af15dcfc7e59775da59f/packages/sp/files/types.ts#L292